# Is it possible to access transactions from the Apple Wallet on IOS?

Tags: ios, swift, applepay

I have looked into the Wallet API, and it doesn't seem like you can retrieve the transactions from there. I am building a personal finance app, and I absolutely need to retrieve the transactions from the wallet.

Do you guys know if there is a way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Absolutely not; It would be a privacy violation.

Comment: seems like "Prison Break" app :)